# Is it possible to reach a computer on a network with a static ip that doesn't belong to the subnet?

Tags: networking, router, ip, routing, subnet

Let's say I have a router at 192.168.0.1. Let's say it's a /16, so it's routing for 192.168.x.x.

I have a desktop on this network at 192.168.0.2.

Let's say someone attaches a new system to the network and gives it the static ip of 10.0.0.2.

Is this system visible to the router via arp? Will it show up via "arp -a -n" on the router? If it's not visible to the router via arp, is it visible via some other method?

Is this system visible to the router or desktop via nmap? If so, how could I locate it assuming I don't know the static ip?

Would I have to scan from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255? (Assuming that the ip isn't necessarily chosen from the standard private ip ranges) If the ip isn't chosen from the standard private ip ranges, how could I scan for this ip without nmap hitting the internet?

Let's say sshd is listening on port 22 on this new system. Would it be reachable from the router? From the desktop? Or would it be unreachable due to the fact that it doesn't have an ip for the appropriate subnet?

Comment: Your questions are rather vague, and the answer to most of the questions is a definite maybe, depending on dozens of factors from what router, what the rogue PC is broadcasting on the network, how the switches handle it, etc... Except the last one, if it was listening on port 22 for ssh connection, could you reach it? No... Not from the router or a desktop.

Comment: The general thrust of your question seems to be "can I detect random devices attached to my network"? And the answer to that is "as long as they don't transmit on their own, it depends on the device - they may or may not respond to various methods of scanning, including ARP".

Comment: this might be helpful to your first question: https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junose15.1/topics/concept/ip-arp-understanding.html